# Trying to interpret jQuery again - how do I pause on video play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

Ok, I'm trying to modify some already written jQuery - as background, I know Javascript decently, but I'm only so-so with jQuery. My understanding of this code is that there's a scrolling bar, which will change every 6 seconds. I am unsure if there's any video specific code in here though - right now the scrollbar has a video embedded on one of the panes, which is clicked on.

What I am trying to do, is set up an image (currently inside `<div class=vid>`, not shown), which when it is clicked, will stop the paning, UNTIL one of the buttons at the bottom is clicked, and it will also play a flash video.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var scroll_item = jQuery("#chained").scrollable({circular: true, mousewheel: false}).navigator().autoscroll({
            interval: 6000,
            autoplay: false,
            autopause: false
        }); 
    window.scroll_control = scroll_item.data("scrollable");


    scroll_control.play();

    var $playBtn =  $('#p-p-btn');

        $playBtn.click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('play')){
                $(this).addClass('pause');
                $(this).removeClass('play');
                scroll_control.play();
            } else if($(this).hasClass('pause')) {
                $(this).addClass('play');
                $(this).removeClass('pause');
                scroll_control.stop();
            };
                                }); 

        jQuery('#chained').hover(
            function() { scroll_control.stop(); },
            function() {
                if ($playBtn.hasClass('pause')) {
                    scroll_control.play();
                    }
                }
            );

    });
</script>
```

I believe all I have to do is add a condition which will determine if the image has been clicked (it is in `<div class=vid>`, but I am going to give it an id as well probably), which will turn the paning off (perhaps by "clicking" the play/off button?), and it will also launch the video with an auto play setting.

Does that sound accurate?

How would I turn the paning off?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the code, because i don't know the whole context.
But try to add this in your document ready:

```
$("#YOURIMAGEID").bind("click",function(){
          scroll_control.stop();
          $('#p-p-btn').addClass('play');
          $('#p-p-btn').removeClass('pause');
         //other logic
});
```

Comment: Stops the control and visualizes the pause button.